# SerializableAttribute usage

Tags: .net, serialization

I need to serialize a class `C` using `BinaryFormatter`.

So I mark `C` as `[Serializable]`.
`C` inherits an *abstract* `B` class.

B is *NOT* marked as `[Serializable]`.
`B` inherits `A` class,

`A` is `[Serializable]` and also it implements `ISerializable`;

What situation can we have?

`AProperty` will be serialized
`BProperty` will *not* be serialized (?)
`CProperty` will be serialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit changes *everything*; if `A` implements `ISerializable` then they *all* implement `ISerializable`. With that, you are using custom serialization so the behaviour is determined ***entirely*** by the `GetObjectData` and serialization-constructor code you write in each of `A` / `B` / `C`.

---

Original answer, when there was no mention of `ISerializable`

serialization is generally based on type of the actual object at runtime, and `BinaryFormatter` (which maps to `[Serializable]`) is a *field* serializer. However, if `B` is not marked `[Serializable]`, it **cannot be serialized** with `BinaryFormatter` (unless it is `ISerializable`); so:

- if it is an `A`, all `A` fields will be serialized
- if it is a `C`, it will throw an exception
- (it can't be a `B` since that is abstract; but if it was, that would throw too)

If you *aren't* using `BinaryFormatter` (and personally I don't think `BinaryFormatter` is a good choice most of the time), then the behaviour will depend on the specific serializer.

My advice: use a different serializer; there are plenty. Almost all are (IMO) better choices than `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: @serhio - see update; in short: with custom serialization that is *entirely* up to your custom code

Comment: @serhio there is no `[Serialized]`; note that `[Serializable]` just means "figure it out yourself" (i.e. serialize all fields that aren't marked `[NonSerialized]`) - if you implement `ISerializable` then  both `[Serializable]` and `[NonSerialized]` are largely redundant, since ***your code*** is doing the serialization

Comment: my fault... I used VB.NET and a class SerializableObject that was coded by a Canadian guy. That one ignored abstract class serialization attribute, that why I had strange behavior (details, if interested http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/serializevbclasses.aspx?msg=3891187#xx3891187xx). Thank you.

Comment: @serhio: "... that was coded by a Canadian guy." And his nationality is relevant how?

Answer (score 0):

try using other Serialization techniques, like Google's Protofol Buffers, that saves you from rebuilding your whole app which consumes this serialized object when you change your AProperty class.

JSON is another option.

Comment: I can't. Too much to change. And this was not the question about.

Comment: i know, it is just i had the same issue and finally gave up on all these attributes and constant changes and decided to use non binary formatter which is backward compatible

Answer (score 0):

if A is a base class and it is serizable then B will automatically becomes serizable.

Comment: no no no... this is not about [serrializable] attribute. You should mention it in every class, inherited or not.